# Certain plotting functions are setting variables unwantedly

Tags: plotting, visualization, variable-definitions, assignment

I came across the following problem. Certain plotting functions set variables to values, which I do not want. For example, if I run `SliceVectorPlot3D` with an example from the documentation,

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Then after I run above line the `x`, `y` and `z` symbols are all set to the value of `2`. I cannot clear those variables with `ClearAll`, only by calling `Remove` onto them.

`DensityPlot3D` also has this problem and other 3D plotting functions do this as well. But not all of them; `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot3D` leave the variables unallocated.

I have no idea if this is intended behavior, but I would love it if I can prevent these functions from setting the variables. I am running Mathematica version 12.2.0.0 on Arch Linux. My Windows machine running the same version of Mathematica has the same behavior for the plotting functions.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in versions 12.0+ (does not happen in version 11.3 (windows 10-64bit)). Please report to wolfram support. (Btw, `Clear` also works).

Comment: You can use `Block[{x, y, z}, plt = SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]]` to isolate the plot variables from the global context.

Comment: Does not happen in 12.1

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Good to see that it is not a problem with my machine. @BobHanlon Thank you for the workaround, I will try it.

Comment: @kglr Yes, I indeed meant DensityPlot3D, I edited my post.

Comment: Really weird that `ClearAll` doesn't work because it seems to think `x` is somehow *still* a local variable...what could be going on here?